# Make Chrome notification indicator icon stay permanently

Tags: google-chrome, indicator

Chrome provides the following notification icon indicator:

[image]

The indicator context menu entry provides a useful option to temporarily mute notifications.

However, the indicator icons disappears automatically after having read a notification, thus making the context menu and the mute option inaccessible.

Is it possible to make the indicator icon stay permanently in the tray icon bar?